# Master Gridview binding

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having a gridview and 2 link button in the gird view,Edit and delete, When the edit button s is clicked , the details of that row should be displayed in the 'detailsview'.And my details view is in the update panel.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set the CommandName property of the buttons in the gridview to say "Edit" and "Delete". Then catch these clicks in RowCommand event i.e.

```
Protected Sub yourGridView_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles yourGridView.RowCommand
     If e.CommandName = "Edit" Then
          'Set details View with appropriate values
     End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use itemtemplet in gridview control and go through this link ----
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/GridViewConfirmDelete.aspx